# Почему не срабатывает break?

Tags: java

```
 public static void game(int random, int number) throws IOException {





            while (number != 0 && number !=random) { 


            {
                if (number == 0 ) {break;}
                else {

                    if (number > random) System.out.println("Число меньше");
                    if (number < random) System.out.println("Число больше");

                    game(random, enterNumber());
                }
            }

        }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы же  в цикле прописали `number != 0`, значит 0 уже не допускается, а вы делаете проверку на 0 внутри цикла, хотя он там никак не окажется

Answer (score 4):

```
if (number == 0 ) {break;}
```

не имеет смыла, так как

```
 while (number != 0)
```

цикл while допускает number который не равен нулю, то есть number не может содержать ноль